# Custom xib view is not visibly displayed when programmatically invoked

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xib, programmatically-created

Here are several properties which I have already checked.

- `isHidden = false`
- `(lldb) po ghostingShimmerView.frame
  ▿ (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
    ▿ origin : (0.0, 0.0)
      - x : 0.0
      - y : 0.0
    ▿ size : (375.0, 667.0)
      - width : 375.0
      - height : 667.0`
- The xib's instance is not nil,  `ShimmerView: 0x7fea24914d90; frame = (0 0; 375 667); layer = <CALayer: 0x608000225440>>`
- When I click on `debug view hierarchy` button, I can clearly see the xib's view is present, and no views are in front of it, however in the simulator and phone it is not displaying.

What are the other potential causes?

Comment: do you add it to a window or view that is visible, if so are you doing it in the visible frame?

Comment: Can you make sure it's added to the front that there is no other view above it

Comment: @GradyPlayer, to a view that is visible.  Yes, in the visible frame.  @Sh_Khan yes, I added it to the front and no view is in front of it as confirmed by the `debug view hierarchy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other thing I can think of that could cause this is a `mask`, or a `low alpha value`.